# Effect of overtime hours on morale / retention at a job?

Tags: cognitive-modeling

I'm unsure if this is the place to ask, but I'm curious as to if there have been any studies on the effect of overtime hours worked and how it affects morale and possibly retention at a job? Additionally, the same information on hours cut could suffice. I'm trying to mathematically model it for work.

If anyone has any insight I'd greatly appreciate it! I've been trying to search the internet and it seems like a popular thing to learn in psychology or business school, but I'm coming up short with information!

Comment: There's a workplace.SE but I think the question is reasonably on-topic here as well. On the workplace site people often answer just from their own experience, so a literature-based question is probably better off here.

Comment: Probably a decent starting point is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effects_of_overtime#Mental_effects Some of the effect you're looking for are going to be indirect.